# Javascript regex find variables in a math equation

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find in a math expression elements that are not wrapped between `{` and `}`

**Examples:**

- Input: `abc+1*def`
  Matches: `["abc", "1", "def"]`
- Input: `{abc}+1+def`
  Matches: `["1", "def"]`
- Input: `abc+(1+def)`
  Matches: `["abc", "1", "def"]`
- Input: `abc+(1+{def})`
  Matches: `["abc", "1"]`
- Input: `abc def+(1.1+{ghi})`
  Matches: `["abc def", "1.1"]`
- Input: `1.1-{abc def}`
  Matches: `["1.1"]`

**Rules**

- The expression is well-formed. (So there won't be start parenthesis without closing parenthesis or starting `{` without `}`)
- The math symbols allowed in the expression are `+` `-` `/` `*` and `(` `)`
- Numbers could be decimals.
- Variables could contains spaces.
- Only one level of `{` `}` (no nested brackets)

So far, I ended with: http://regex101.com/r/gU0dO4

```
(^[^/*+({})-]+|(?:[/*+({})-])[^/*+({})-]+(?:[/*+({})-])|[^/*+({})-]+$)
```

I split the task into 3:

- match elements at the beginning of the string
- match elements that are between two { and }
- match elements at the end of the string

But it doesn't work as expected.

Any idea ?

Comment: Consider going the other way as the first (and independent) step - replace all "{..}" with "".

Comment: Using regex to validate parenthesis pairs is already well complicated, for the sanity of the maintainer consider alternatives to doing it in regex.

Comment: I do not want to validate the expression, I know for sure that the expression is valid. I just want to get the tokens that are not wrapped between { and }.

Comment: Do you have only one level of { } or can you have deep nesting (which changes everything and would require a parsing) ?

Comment: I updated the question to make it clear: no nesting, only one level of { }

Comment: This **really** changes everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an interesting regexp challenge, but in the real world you'd be much better off simply finding all `[^+/*()-]+` groups and removing those enclosed in `{}`'s

```
"abc def+(1.1+{ghi})".match(/[^+/*()-]+/g).filter(
    function(x) { return !/^{.+?}$/.test(x) })
// ["abc def", "1.1"]
```

That being said, regexes is not a correct way to parse math expressions. For serious parsing, consider using formal grammars and parsers. There are plenty of parser generators for javascript, for example, in [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/online) you can write a grammar like

```
expr
  = left:multiplicative "+" expr
  / multiplicative

multiplicative
  = left:primary "*" right:multiplicative
  / primary

primary
  = atom
  / "{" expr "}"
  / "(" expr ")"

atom = number / word

number = n:[0-9.]+ { return parseFloat(n.join("")) }
word = w:[a-zA-Z ]+ { return w.join("") }
```

and generate a parser which will be able to turn

```
 abc def+(1.1+{ghi})
```

into

```
[
   "abc def",
   "+",
   [
      "(",
      [
         1.1,
         "+",
         [
            "{",
            "ghi",
            "}"
         ]
      ],
      ")"
   ]
]
```

Then you can iterate this array just normally and fetch the parts you're interested in.

Comment: Fails for nesting, and more complex cases.

Comment: Thanks for fixing your answer :)

Comment: I accept this answer for the match and filter expression which work well and is simple. Not for the grammar and parser explication.

Answer (score 3):

Matching `{}`s, especially nested ones is hard (read impossible) for a standard regular expression, since it requires counting the number of `{`s you encountered so you know which `}` terminated it.

Instead, a simple string manipulation method could work, this is a very basic parser that just reads the string left to right and consumes it when outside of parentheses.

```
var input = "abc def+(1.1+{ghi})"; // I assume well formed, as well as no precedence
var inParens = false;
var output = [], buffer = "", parenCount = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if(!inParens){
          if(input[i] === "{"){
              inParens = true;
              parenCount++;
          } else if (["+","-","(",")","/","*"].some(function(x){ 
               return x === input[i]; 
          })){ // got symbol
              if(buffer!==""){ // buffer has stuff to add to input
                  output.push(buffer); // add the last symbol
                  buffer = "";
              }
          } else { // letter or number
              buffer += input[i]; // push to buffer
          }
    } else { // inParens is true
         if(input[i] === "{") parenCount++;
         if(input[i] === "}") parenCount--;
         if(parenCount === 0) inParens = false; // consume again
    }
}
```

Comment: ITT people who know the difference between a regular and a context free language and people who don't :(

Comment: Note : this answer (and comments) were made when OP hadn't said there was only one level of {} at most. Initially, this was the only correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The variable names you mentioned can be match by `\b[\w.]+\b` since they are strictly bounded by word separators

Since you have well formed formulas, the names you don't want to capture are strictly followed by `}`, therefore you can use a lookahead expression to exclude these :

```
(\b[\w.]+ \b)(?!})
```

Will match the required elements (http://regexr.com/38rch).

**Edit:**

For more complex uses like correctly matching :

- abc {def{}}
- abc def+(1.1+{g{h}i})

We need to change the lookahead term to `(?|({|}))`

To include the match of `1.2-{abc def}` we need to change the `\b`<sup>1</sup>. This term is using lookaround expression which are not available in javascript. So we have to work around.

```
(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0-9. ])([a-zA-Z0-9. ]+(?=[^0-9A-Za-z. ]))(?!({|}))
```

Seems to be a good one for our examples (http://regex101.com/r/oH7dO1).

<sup>1</sup> `\b` is the separation between a `\w` and a `\W` `\z` or `\a`. Since `\w` does not include space and `\W` does, it is incompatible with the definition of our variable names.

Comment: Nearly close to what I need. I just added the space to handle the last exampe: match "abc def" and not "abc" and "def": `(\b[\w. ]+\b)(?!})`

Comment: Oh my bad. I forgot to report it after changing to `\w`. Good catch.

Comment: This would still easily fail for more complex expressions. For example - `abc {def{}}`

Comment: You can fine tune a bit the lookahead expression with things like `(?!(}|{))` if you want to exclude `{g{h}i}` inputs.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The question has been edited to precise there's only one level of {}

Comment: This solution failed on the input `1.2-{abc def}` it will match abc.

Comment: This fails because of the meaning of `\w` / `\b`. See edit in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Going forward with user2864740's comment, you can replace all things between `{}` with empty and then match the remaining.

```
var matches = "string here".replace(/{.+?}/g,"").match(/\b[\w. ]+\b/g);
```

Since you know that expressions are valid, just select `\w+`

Comment: I edited your regex to also allow spaces and decimal dots within match results. The word boundaries are to make sure we start and end with a "word" character.

Comment: Fails for `"abc def+(1.1+{g{h}i})".replace(/{.+?}/g,"").match(/\b[\w. ]+\b/g);`

Comment: Also fails for `"abc def+(1.1+{{}ghi})".replace(/{.+?}/g,"").match(/\b[\w. ]+\b/g);` Both of these are pefectly valid expressions by the way.

Comment: You could use a loop. Test for /{[^}]+}/ if it matches replace with "" and repeat. If it does not match your done.